# \multiinclude doesn't work as intended

Tags: beamer

If I use \multiinclude on several images only the first one gets included.

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{xmpmulti}
 
 \begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
            \multiinclude[format=png, graphics={width=\textwidth}]{test/Brownian}
        \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

In my folder "test" my png files are named "Brownian-0.png" and so on.
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Logs:
[file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/88rgwfscs4b6fkm/document.log/file)

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Can you a) state where your tex file is located in relation to the test folder b) show your .log file so we can see which engine etc. you use.

Comment: a) My texfile and my folder "test" are in the same location, in "test" are my png's
b) I added the start of my log, is this enough for you?
PS: What a honor to get an answer from you! I try to implement a gif in my presentation for 3 hours via your instructions from other questions :D

Comment: Can you please show your complete .log file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Edited in

Comment: Thanks. The odd thing in the log file is it picks up a graphic with two file types: `test/Brownian-0.png.png` This looks fishy. Can you check your image files that they are correctly named?

Comment: Yeah, that was the reason. I renamed them because I was desperately looking for a mistake. I've included around a 100 png, it compiles forever and ends with an error. The error I implemeted at least gave me a pdf since it only compiled 1 png. So I'll probably scale the number of png down a bit. Anyway thanks for your kind support.

Comment: 100 pngs as such shouldn't be a problem by itself. If you manage to make a minimal non-working example you could ask a new question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it turns out the issue was with how the images were names and not a tex problem